# Solving the Diophantine equation $4x^3 + 27y^2 - z^2 = 0$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

This question is inspired by trying to find cubic polynomials whose discriminant is the negative of a perfect square.

Essentially the polynomial $t^3 + pt + q$ has discriminant $\Delta = -4p^3 - 27q^2$. So if $\Delta = -z^2$ then (after renaming the variables $p$ and $q$ to $x$ and $y$ respectively), we get the equation:

$$4x^3 + 27y^2 - z^2 = 0$$

I'm looking for integer solution of this equation, but I don't know how to tackle it.

---

I know this equation does have non-trivial solutions, because $(-3n^2,4n^3,18n^3)$ is a solution for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But can someone help me with generating more?

Comment: Can you pls explain what do you mean by "I know this equation does have non-trivial solutions, because $(-3n^2,4n^3,18n^3)$ is a solution for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$."

Comment: @GooglePlayGames Sure, I mean that $4(-3n^2)^3 + 27(4n^3)^2 - (18n^3)^2 = 0$.

Comment: I’d rewrite it as $z^2-3(3y)^2=4x^3$ and use that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt3]$ is a UFD.

Comment: $\{ -147, 686, 0 \}, \{-27, -54, 0 \}$

Comment: $(16,0,128)$ and $(13,34,200)$

Comment: Given any $u,v$ you can let $x=u^2-27v^2$ and $y=2vx, z=2ux.$

Comment: If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, so is $(x,26y\pm 5z,26z\pm 135y).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $$   X= 2 x^3+ 162xy^2 $$
$$  Y = 6x^2 y + 54 y^3 $$
$$ Z = x^2 - 27 y^2, $$
then $$ X^2 - 27 Y^2  = 4 Z^3  $$

I see, I have permuted the variable names   compared with the question.  Sigh

Starting over...

A bit more generally,

if $$   X=  x^3 -3Cxy^2 - BCy^3 $$
$$  Y = 3x^2 y +3Bxy^2 + (B^2-C) y^3 $$
$$ Z = x^2 + Bxy +C y^2, $$
then $$ X^2 +BXY+C Y^2  =  Z^3  $$

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: This is perfect for me, thank you

Comment: @Will Jagy I have noticed that any choices of your parameter end up with a cubic which has a rational root, is there a reason for this? I guess I'm not completely sure how you constructed your expression.

Comment: @SamForster  this is Gauss composition for the form $x^2 - 27 y^2.$ It is also what happens if you follow the first comment of Thomas Andrews. A similar thing can be done for any   quadratic form  $x^2 + B xy + C y^2$   with fist coefficient $1$